# Count distinct monthly running total

Tags: sql, unique, distinct

I am trying to find a SQL query to the question of finding the running unique count of distinct customers each month.

This is not the number of distinct  customers each month, but rather what is the new incremental total number of unique customers as each month rolls by.

For example, in January I had 10 unique customers and in February I had another 10 customers, but 5 of these who transacted in February were repeat customers and had also transacted in January; so between January and February I really only have a running total of 15 unique customers (10 in January and 5 in February).

What would be the simplest solution to achieve the running unique customer count for each month of the year?

Example Output where (compared to January) in February there were an additional 5 unique customers and in March there were an additional 10 unique customers

[image]

Comment: share sample table with data and expected oputput and fiddle is always appreciate

Comment: Thanks and example output table above : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do:

```
Select 
   month, 
   count(*) as custs, 
   (select 
        count(distinct cust_id)
    from mytable b 
    where b.month<=a.month) as RunningUniqueCusts 
From mytable a
group by month
```

Or for month & region

```
Select 
   month, 
   region,
   count(*) as custs, 
   (select 
        count(distinct cust_id)
    from mytable b 
    where b.month<=a.month 
     and b.region=a.region) as RunningUniqueCustsForRegion
From mytable a
group by month, region
```

**Update 3-Mar-2022**
The following would return the unique customer ids for each month where they didn't appear previously:

```
SELECT TM.MONTH_ID, TM.CUST_ID 
FROM MYTABLE as TM 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
     (SELECT 1
      FROM MYTABLE as PM 
      WHERE PM.CUST_ID = TM.CUST_ID
      and PM.MONTH < TM.MONTH)
GROUP BY TM.MONTH_ID, TM.CUST_ID
ORDER BY TM.MONTH_ID, TM.CUST_ID
```

Comment: Thank you! That looks like it has done the trick perfectly! I just added a group by clause for the month and the query seems to do the job! Thanks : )

Comment: if I wanted to further split this by Region (North, South etc.) what revision would be required because you can’t do a over partition by with the unique count?

Comment: added an alternative with region.

Comment: I have one final question - if I want to get a list of all the unique customers (CUST_ID) in each time period - how would I do this? Thank you again!

Comment: That would be a separate query, wouldn't it? something like `SELECT MONTH, CUST_ID FROM MYTABLE GROUP BY MONTH, CUST_ID`. If it is more complex than this ask a new question and show your sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Hmmm I guess I am saying if the unique increase from Jan to Feb is 10 new customers - what would these unique customer ids be? Because at the moment we just get 10 but I don’t know the ID numbers of the new 10 customers...? I have a CUST_ID field...

Comment: So you could use SELECT  CUST_ID FROM MYTABLE WHERE Month between '2021-01' and '2021-02' GROUP BY  CUST_ID would give you unique customer_ids in that period.

Comment: Yep sure, so is there a way to write the query so I can do that for month after month (I have three years of monthly data) ensuring only new unique customers are returned each month?

Comment: Added and update.